# trying to put margin around the content div

Tags: css

been trying to put margin around content div, but its not working , please help have a look at the html and css is below

```
<?php require_once("include/session.php");?>
<?php require_once("include/functions.php");?>
<?php include("include/mheader.php");?>
<div id="content">
<h3>
    Registration.
</h3>
<p>
Please read the terms and condition before you register
Simply click on register on the home page, and fill in the registration form.
On submission of the registration form, an email will be sent to the registered email on the form, from which you can activate your account
</p>


</div>
<?php include("include/footer.php");?>
```

the css is below(was thinking #content {margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;}  this should do it , but its not working

```
body,html {
    margin: 0;
}

#page {
    width: 1060px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative
    /* is the same as: 
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 */
}

/* sticky footer */
/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;
}
#outer:after {
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    height:1%;
    content:" ";
}
/* ...#003399;#383838; */
/*
CSS for Reacheasy site
*/
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
background:#cccccc;
}
#outer {
    width:1060px;
    margin:auto;
    min-height:100%;
    margin-top:-52px;
    border-left:1px solid #cccccc;
    border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
background: white url(backgrounds/nav-bg.jpg) repeat-y left top    
}
* html #outer {
    height:100%
}
/*h1,h3 {
    font-size: xx-large;

    text-shadow: 10px 10px 1px grey;

    color: #000;
    padding: 2em 0 .2em .4em;
    margin: 0;

    background: white url(img/header.jpg) repeat-y right;

}*/
ul#nav {
    height: 2em;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .2em 0;
    margin:0;
    background:url(img/tabs.gif);
}
ul#nav li {
    /* 
    background: #48f url(img/tabs.gif);
    */
      display : block;
  background-color : #666666;
     float: left;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #A1A1A1;
}
ul#nav a {
    background: url(img/tabs.gif) 100% 0;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#nav li.current {
    background-color:#666666 ;
    background-position: 0 -60px;
}
ul#nav li.current a {
    background-position: 100% -60px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#content {
margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;

}
```

this is the header

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Reacheasy - Foremost website for easy reach of things globally</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<link href="members.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  
</head>
  <body>
<div id="outer">
<div id="page">
<div id="header">
<div id="hlogo">
<span style="float:right;"><img src="img/relogo.jpg"  class="logoImage" width="96" height="96"/></span>
</div>
 <span style="font-size:small;text-shadow: 10px 10px 1px grey;"><h1>Reacheasy<span style="font-size:small;"><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></span></h1></span>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li class="current"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="women.php">Women</a></li>
     <li><a href="men.php">Men</a></li>
     <li><a href="children.php">Children</a></li>
     <li><a href="homeandappliances.php">Home&amp;Appliances</a></li>
     <li><a href="visionandsound.php">Vision&amp;Sounds</a></li>
      <li><a href="motoring.php">Motoring</a></li>
      <li><a href="homemore.php">More</a></li>
      <li><a href="howto.php">Help(How to?)</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> <!--end of navigation div -->
</div>
```

the footer

```
<div id="footer">


&copy; 2012 Reacheasy
<ul id="footlink">
     <li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
     <li><a href="termsandcondition.php">Terms&amp;Condition</a></li>
     <li><a href="faq.php">Faq</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample? This code looks fine although there are some weird rules like `margin-top:-32767px;`. -- What HTML is include in the header and footer?

Comment: @Smamatti I HAVE INCLUDED the header and the footer

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle.net instead

Comment: this is the link http://reacheasy.co.uk/howto.php

Comment: Where is an element with `content` there is nothing on it

Comment: @lostty84 Please see Starx's answer below.

Comment: @TJ. thats true, do you have any clue on that because av uploaded it

Comment: its seeing it now, dont know why, thanks

Answer (score 2):

IMO, this is a problem caused by unclosed tag.  As per your post, your `<div id="outer">` is not closed. Try to fix that.

---

I was right. See [this](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://reacheasy.co.uk/howto.php) validator result

> Line 82, Column 7: end tag for "div" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was
>   specified
>
> You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to
>   "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".

---

**Update:** There is no element with id `content` on the page you linked, so the rule of margin will not be applied until such element exist on the first place.

Comment: Actually there is an element with #content, see the first html block in the question.

Comment: @TJ. But not in the link he provided. See that too

Comment: Oh my! I just tested the code in the questions and the margin is applied perfectly. The link is missing #content as you said.

Comment: @TJ. I know, that's why I mentioned it. I test that already too myself. :)

Comment: @TJ.,@Starx is div id="content", not specifying it with the css #content

Comment: @lostty84, It is, but view the source, there is no element with id="content".

Comment: @Starx thats true, do you have any clue on that because av uploaded it

Comment: @lostty84, So the margin is working now. Be sure to close the `<div id="outer">`

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). To see this in effect, apply `border:1px solid` on #content.